# Generate a report of entire D: Drive using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting

I am new to PowerShell scripting. For one of my School project I need to generate a report of the entire D Drive. I need to list all the folders sorted according to the size

**Summary of the work I have done so far:** 
I have installed a PowerShell module from this website 
https://www.gngrninja.com/script-ninja/2016/5/24/powershell-calculating-folder-sizes
using Install-Module PSFolderSize

After installing if I run the command ***Get-FolderSize*** I'm getting the FolderSize for the path I'm running from. The foldersize is not running for all the folders in the directory. 
I am facing difficulty traversing through all the folders.

Expected Output:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+
| FolderName  | Size(Bytes)  |   Size(MB)   | Size(GB)  |       FullPath        | HostName  | 
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+
| Disney      | 454545448889 | 433488.32024 | 423.32844 | D:\Videos\Disney      | localhost |  
| Universal   |  25454544884 | 24275.34569  | 23.70639  | D:\Videos\Universal   | localhost |  
| Fox Studios |   8803063287 | 8395.25536   | 8.19849   | D:\Videos\Fox Studios | localhost |  
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

Can anyone help me where to start?

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.*

Comment: there are limits on what PoSh can see when looking at the file system. hte most common of those limits are ... `permission to see something` & `total path length`. ///// you will need to identify a specific item that is causing problems and then investigate that item to determine the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use other tools (like TreeSize) for creating reports like this because of the speed and long filename problematics.
However you could solve your task with the following powershell command without downloading an other Module.
For each subfolder inside your D:\ you have to receive your required data.
You have to calculate the size of each directory by looking for each file `Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder.FullName -Recurse -Force` and sum up the lenght of all files.
Here you can use the `Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum`. Depending on the directory size this task will take some time.
Take a look [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/) if you struggle with long file name issues.
After collection and adding all data to an output variable use `Select-Object -Property 'FolderName', 'Size(Bytes)', 'Size(MB)', 'Size(GB)', 'FullPath', 'HostName'` for sorting the header order.
The command `Sort-Object -Property 'Size(Bytes)', 'FolderName'` will sort the output depending on the folder size and name.
For a nice looking output use `Format-Table`.

```
[System.String]$Path = 'D:\'
[PSCustomObject[]]$Output = @()
foreach ($Folder in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory))
{
    [System.Int64]$Size = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder.FullName -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
    [System.Collections.Hashtable]$Hashtable = @{
        'FolderName' = $Folder.Name
        'Size(Bytes)' = $Size
        'Size(MB)' = $Size / 1MB
        'Size(GB)' = $Size / 1GB
        'FullPath' = $Folder.FullName
        'HostName' = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    }
    $Output += New-Object -TypeName 'PSCustomObject' -Property $Hashtable
}

$Output | `
    Select-Object -Property 'FolderName', 'Size(Bytes)', 'Size(MB)', 'Size(GB)', 'FullPath', 'HostName' | `
    Sort-Object -Property 'Size(Bytes)', 'FolderName' | `
    Format-Table
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. Your solution did not solve my problem entirely but it helped me solve my problem. I updated your code to include hidden folders and all child folders as well. See my answer below for the perfect answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.String]$Path = 'D:\'
[PSCustomObject[]]$Output = @()

foreach ($Folder in (Get-ChildItem -Recurse $Path | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }))
{
    [System.Int64]$Size = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder.FullName -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum
    [System.Collections.Hashtable]$Hashtable = @{
        'FolderName' = $Folder.Name
        'Size(Bytes)' = $Size
        'Size(MB)' = [Math]::Round($Size / 1MB ,2)
        'Size(GB)' = [Math]::Round($Size / 1GB,2)
        'FullPath' = $Folder.FullName
        'HostName' = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    }
    $Output += New-Object -TypeName 'PSCustomObject' -Property $Hashtable
}

$Output | `
    Select-Object -Property 'FolderName', 'Size(Bytes)', 'Size(MB)', 'Size(GB)', 'FullPath', 'HostName' | `
    Sort-Object -Property 'Size(Bytes)' , 'FolderName' -Descending | `
    Format-Table
```

Comment: Depending on your powershell version `Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }` is not necessary because `Get-ChildItem` supports the `-Directory` switch. And I'm still confused why you use the `-Recurse` parameter inside the foreach loop... I thought you need the report only for the "first" level inside D:\. However I'm glad my sample helped you! :-)